# Angular Mat Select Trigger with FormControl

Tags: angular

Angular material select dropdown with mat select trigger.

Trying to create select dropdown like this :

https://stackblitz.com/angular/omvmgjjbnnq?file=app%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts

My Code :

component.ts

```
export class SelectCustomTriggerExample implements OnInit {
  dispForm : FormGroup
  constructor(private fb : FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dispForm = this.fb.group({
        toppings : ['']
     })
  }


  toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
}
```

component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <form [formGroup]="dispForm">
  <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" formControlName="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-select-trigger>
      {{toppings.value ? toppings.value[0] : ''}}
      <span *ngIf="toppings.value?.length > 1" class="example-additional-selection">
        (+{{toppings.value.length - 1}} {{toppings.value?.length === 2 ? 'other' : 'others'}})
      </span>
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  </form>
</mat-form-field>
```

I have changed formControl to formControlName and code stopped working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code defines two form controls. When using `[formControl]`, you're using only one of them: the one created using `toppings = new FormControl();`.

When using `formControlName`, you're using both: the one created using `toppings : ['']` is the one bound to your select, and the other one is the one used by your trigger.

There should be only one form control. And all the code should use that using form control.

Replace, in your component,

```
toppings = new FormControl();
```

by

```
get toppings(): FormControl {
  return this.dispForm.get('toppings') as FormControl;
}
```

Also, your form is named `dispForm`, not `dispform`. And it must be `formControlName="toppings"`, not `[formControlName]="toppings"`.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-igt6yh?file=app/select-custom-trigger-example.html)

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet . By default toppings will be FormControl as we have used that in FormGroup. Then we we are again making that as form control in get () method ?

Comment: Because FormGroup.get() returns AbstractControl. You know that the concrete type is FormControl. But the TypeScript compiler does not.

Comment: Also, If I'm getting ToppingList from API, then html is throwing error stating that "Cannot read property 'Value' of undefined"

Comment: Well, loading data with http is asynchronous. Between the moment when you send the request and the moment when the response comes back, the data stays uninitialized, thus undefined. Use ngIf to not use this data until it's defined.